# Cannot display shapes in the price graph

Tags: pine-script

everybody,

Why doesn't this indicator show the arrows in the price chart?

It displays the arrows in the banana indicator but not in the price chart.

Do you know why?

Thank you

```
    //@version=4
study(title="rsi", shorttitle="rsi", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(2, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

plotshape(series= rsi >= 70 and rsi >= rsi[1], style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=#4CAF50, size=size.small, text="70")
plotshape(series=rsi <= 30 and rsi <= rsi[1], style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=#BD494C, size=size.small, text="30")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display your indicator in the price chart then you should set `overlay` argument of `study()` to `true`.

```
study(title="rsaaai", shorttitle="rsi", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="", overlay=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much...
Do you think it is possible to combine the above code with this code?

```
    //@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#8E1599)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#C0C0C0)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#C0C0C0)
fill(band1, band0, color=#9915FF, transp=90, title="Background")
```

Comment: You shouldn't post answers as comments. Also, you should ask one question per post. As a quick answer, yes, it is possible. just try it and ask a new question if you can't manage it to work.